# CSS issue on my website, can someone help?

Tags: css, layout

I need some help sorting out a CSS issue with my website, I have tried everything I can think of but none worked the way that I wanted.

You can view the issue I have here: http://dev.michaelcarrano.com/blog.html

You will notice the tabs are floating instead of being connected to the content part below it.

Here is a link to the CSS file: [dev.michaelcarrano.com/css/general.css](http://dev.michaelcarrano.com/css/general.css)

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so a number of changes should be made. The main problem is your `<span class="clear"></span>` is actually taking up vertical space.

So, first delete `<span class="clear"></span>` entirely so your HTML should be:

```
<ul class="menu"> ... </ul>
<div class="content"> ...
```

Next, in your CSS, add these rules (You should add them in the existing blocks if they exist):

```
div.content {
  clear: left
}

ul.menu {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%
}

#container #search {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first `#container ul.menu li`, add `margin-top: 8px;`. And remove `margin-top:1px;` from the second `#container ul.menu li`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other suggestions, you should consider setting a more specific DOCTYPE.  It helps make your site render more consistently in different browsers.  See [Fix Your Site With the Right DOCTYPE!](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this changing one simple attribute:

```
#container ul.menu li#search
{
    margin: -5px 0px -10px;
}
```

Comment: Dude, whats up with the big font?

Comment: Trying to get more attention to his answer, despite it being a cheesy fix.

Comment: it was just a bug, your attention isn't required.